# Time inside run() method

Tags: java, android

I have a simple game loop inside the `run()` method. The class is implementing `Runnable`. I just want to create some simple timing code to keep track of the time the player as been playing. Let's say I want to end the game after two minutes.

I'm not sure I doing this right because the time I get on the screen isn't seconds, it's the `long` time format like 1370502588. What Am I doing wrong?

Here is part of the code inside the `run()` method:

```
// Game loop ---------------------------------------
@Override
public void run() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

// Time 
long startGameTime = 0;
long milliSeconds;
int seconds;

while (gameRunning) {
  if (!surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid())
    continue;

  try {
    milliSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis() - startGameTime;
    seconds = (int) (milliSeconds / 1000);
    if (seconds > 120)
      // Game over
      canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
      ...
```

EDIT: LogCat

```
06-06 07:27:06.831: E/Trace(864): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-06 07:27:07.601: D/libEGL(864): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
06-06 07:27:07.611: D/(864): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a142400, tid 864
06-06 07:27:07.721: D/libEGL(864): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
06-06 07:27:07.721: D/libEGL(864): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
06-06 07:27:07.731: D/dalvikvm(864): GC_CONCURRENT freed 232K, 10% free 7430K/8199K, paused 99ms+117ms, total 354ms
06-06 07:27:07.801: W/EGL_emulation(864): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-06 07:27:07.821: D/OpenGLRenderer(864): Enabling debug mode 0
06-06 07:27:08.121: I/Choreographer(864): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-06 07:27:08.201: W/dalvikvm(864): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
06-06 07:27:08.211: E/AndroidRuntime(864): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-88
06-06 07:27:08.211: E/AndroidRuntime(864): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
06-06 07:27:08.211: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at android.view.Surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(Native Method)
06-06 07:27:08.211: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at android.view.SurfaceView$4.unlockCanvasAndPost(SurfaceView.java:785)
06-06 07:27:08.211: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at se.test.game.GameLoop.run(GameLoop.java:269)
06-06 07:27:08.211: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: can you post your logcat?. are you updating ui from the timertask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
long startGameTime = 0;
```

do

```
long startGameTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

then, this line you already have makes much more sense:

```
milliSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis() - startGameTime;
```

In your version, you are subtracting 0 of the current time, which would mean user has been playing since Jan. 1, 1970. In my version, you subtract the real start time from the current time, and the result is the time span in between those two moments.

Comment: 1:0, you beat me now :) +1

Comment: @Andremoniy: now we're even ;)

Comment: @jlordo Thanks for the answer, but I get some problem! The app just close down after I changed to long startGameTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); What could be wrong?

Comment: @3D-kreativ: Hard to tell without stacktrace or logcat

Comment: The LogCat says IllegalArgumentException

Comment: @3D-kreativ: Can you just post the complete logcat in your question? On which line does the `IllegalArgumentException` occur. This seems to be a complete new question by the way. I can't imagine that this happens in your time measuring code.

Comment: I don't have any info about that. There is no error indication inside the code, like red line below the code

Comment: @3D-kreativ: That's because `IllegalArgumentException` is a runtime exception, which is not caught at compile time. Read my comment above. I've updated it while you were replying me.

Comment: Your if(seconds>120) doesn't look like it's using a {...} - I don't know if that's a typo - but if it isn't then maybe you're running the code it protected when seconds isn't larger than 120.

Comment: Thanks! with {...} it's working! I just wrote an comment there, but without the brackets the code below will run when seconds > 120.

Answer (score 0):

startGameTime sis always 0, because it is local to run() and never updated.